# How do I tell Mew to automatically fetch new messages?

Tags: email, emacs

I have recently been trying out Mew for reading email in Emacs. I have successfully connected an IMAP account and can receive new messages by pressing `s` in Summary Mode. How do I tell Mew to do this automatically in the background?

I realize I could probably write some elisp to do this for me, but I was hoping that Mew had this functionality built in.

Comment: I haven't looked at the source code before, but things like that would need to be set with a timer.  So, you might want to grep the source code for the word `timer` and see what comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to the manual that discusses setting up `biff` with a timer:

http://www.mew.org/en/info/release/mew_9.html#biff

The functionality to check new messages is called biff. With the following configuration Mew sees how many new messages have arrived every 5 minutes.

```
(setq mew-use-biff t)
```

If one or more new messages exist, the total number is displayed in the mode line.

The server and the protocol, which Mew checks, are decided according to ‘mew-proto’ and the "case" (‘mew-case’) on boot time.

With the following configuration, Mew beeps when the number of new messages changes from zero to one or more.

```
(setq mew-use-biff-bell t)
```

To change the interval time of biff, set ‘mew-biff-interval’. Below is an example to set it to 10 minutes.

```
(setq mew-biff-interval 10)
```